# How to assert it renders with the correct json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

I'm developing a JSON API and am trying to write an integration test for a show method. The problem is that I don't know how to test the response. Below I have `assert_response :success` but this line always seems to pass, also when it shouldn't (for example when posting `@author1` instead of `@article1` to the `show_articles_path`, which shouldn't work).

What assert line should I use to test that it successfully displayed?

The route:

```
  show_articles POST   /articles/show/:id(.:format)         articles#show
```

The test:

```
  test "should get show" do
    post show_articles_path(@article1, article: {author_id: @author1.id })
    assert_response :success
  end
```

The method:

```
  def show
    @author = Author.find(params[:article][:author_id])
    article = Article.find(params[:id])
    render json: article
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures). Create a folder under test/fixtures and put your files in there. Typically, I use ERB templates, but lot of people use YAML. Here's a quick example:

```
 <% bar ||= "bar's default value %>
 {
   "foo": "<%= bar %>",
   "baz": "quux"
 }
```

While `bar` has a default value, you can parameterize this when you load the fixture. You compare the response body from your code to the rendered text from the fixture.

You can also iterate in loops:

```
 <% 1000.times do |n| %>
   "username": "<%= "user#{n}" %>"
   "email": "<%= "user#{n}@example.com" %>"
 <% end %>
```